# como criar uma tabela em postgreSQL? como usa o alter table e o drop table? e quais as diferenças de primary key e foreign key?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Pessoal me ajudem com os estudos de postgreSQL.Como criar uma tabela em postgreSQL? como usa o alter table e o drop table? e quais as diferenças de primary key e foreign key ?

Comment: O excelente manual do PostgreSQL será de grande ajuda: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Criar tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(15),
    data DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Deletar tabela:

```
DROP TABLE tabela;
```

Alterar tabela (aqui fica um pouco abstrato, teria que especificar mais):

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ACAO_QUE_VOCE_QUER_EXECUTAR;
```

Chave primária: o que define o elemento atual. Exemplo: a chave primária dos seus documentos para o estado é o seu CPF, enquanto a de uma empresa é o CNPJ.

Chave estrangeira: usada para definir um elemento externo. Exemplo: o táxi da placa XXXX-YYY pertence ao cidadão de CPF 123.456.789-01.

Dica: ao fazer uma pergunta na comunidade, tente ser um pouco mais específico, e ganhará respostas mais precisas ;)